# Android Handler Background

Tags: android, background, handler

I have an application where the user can log in. The login needs to persist. What I do now is test in onPause whether the activity isFinishing(). If not, that must mean the user is leaving the app (or screen is dimmed, or phone call, or whatever). Now I want to log the user out if he doesn't come back within 15 minutes. Is it okay to do a postDelayed(..., 15*60)? Will this get executed in the background? Can I do a network call there to log the user out and how sure am I this actually gets done? In case the app is going to get killed within those 15 minutes, is there a hook where I log the user out?

Comment: I don't know if handlers / looper keep running if actitiy pauses. I would move that web connection part to a service that is not tied to activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible to combine the AlarmManager with a broadcast receiver that captures the Intent generated by it.
This link might be useful:
http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your application will get killed in those 15 minutes. However likely will depend on the device specs, android version, amount of apps running, which apps are running, etc. Because of those variables I would say that relying on your postDelayed would not be sufficient and you should use something like the AlarmManager to register your application so it runs the logout code when fired.

If all you want is to have your application logout whenever the activity is destroyed just put your logout code in the onDestroy() method of your activity

Comment: onDestroy() ? Yes. This occurs whenever your app is destroyed regardless if its from you doing it in your code or from the system shutting it down. Take a look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) to learn about the Android activity lifecycle. It will help you out a good deal with this and is, overall, very useful to know